# bundler error when deploying to openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift

I have a ruby on rails app that was originally on ruby 2.1 but I am deploying it to an enterprise version of the open shift platform, which uses ruby 2.0. I used rvm to install ruby 2.0.0 and created a 2.0.0 gemset, which runs on my development machine.  However, when I deploy to the open shift platform, I get the following error:

```
remote: Building Ruby cartridge
remote: bundle install --deployment --path ./app-root/repo/vendor/bundle
remote: NOTE: You can prevent installing certain Gemfile group using: rhc env set BUNDLE_WITHOUT=groupname
remote: `mri_21` is not a valid platform. The available options are: [:ruby, :ruby_18,
remote: :ruby_19, :ruby_20, :mri, :mri_18, :mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx, :jruby, :mswin,
remote: :mingw, :mingw_18, :mingw_19, :mingw_20]
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 4)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control build'
```

When I google this type of problem, the normal solution is to update bundler. However, the problem appears to be the bundler on the open shift platform. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [bundler issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2428), the problem is that some of the gems listed in the gem file are depending on ruby 2.1.

In my case, I solved the problem by removing the gems in the production group (which included `bye bug` using the command. These gems were for use on heroku so not needed on open shift.

```
rhc env set BUNDLE_WITHOUT=production
```

The actual steps you will need to take depends on the gems in your gem file.